# Prove that a square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A$+ $A^T$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that a real square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ + $A^T$ is positive definite.

**Definition**

> A real square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $\mathbf{x}^TA  \mathbf{x} > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n - \{\mathbf{0}\}$

**Observations**

- I noticed that $A + A^T$ is a real symmetric matrix.
- A symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if every eigenvalue is positive.

I would like a hint on how to begin the question but not the full solution.

Comment: *Hint*. Can you show that $\mathrm{x}^{\mathsf{T}}A\mathrm{x} = \mathrm{x}^{\mathsf{T}}\big(\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{\mathsf{T}})\big)\mathrm{x}$?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is true. $A$ is not necessarily symmetric? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Of course $A$ need not be symmetric. But when you consider the function $\mathrm{x} \mapsto \mathrm{x}^T A \mathrm{x}$, only the 'symmetric part' of $A$ contributes to it. So you can safely replace $A$ in $\mathrm{x}^T A \mathrm{x}$ by its symmetric part $\frac{1}{2}(A^T + A)$.

Comment: Off topic: I'm anxious to watch episode 11.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is clear, for the other note that

$$ x^t A^t x = \sum_{ij}x_i (A^t)_{ij}x_j $$

and try to relate this to the matrix $A$ instead of its transpose.